# Is my Hiragana writing legible and easy to read?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

[image: Hiragana writing test]

I just want to make sure that if I were to be asked to write something out in Hiragana, it would be easy to understand.

Comment: I think you need more exercises for ね、れ、わ.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep working on those. Glad to hear that most of them are legiable at least.

Comment: Not only legible. I'd say you're doing pretty d*mn well, actually =) Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvUoakQf3I8), which snail plane has recommended here before, and keep practising in squares.

Comment: Thanks for such a possitive responce Earthliry, definately will check out the video. Also, I took a close look at what I was doing wrong with ね、れ、わ. and it turns out that I just wasn't pulling my pen back up far enough on the second strokes. I will definately keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your writing is, by and large, legible and I don't think anyone should misunderstand you. However, there are several points I must make (also see the image below):

1. Some kana are definitely unbalanced, notably そ, ね, れ, わ. A few other characters have curves that aren't in right places too, but they're matter of practicing, I guess.
2. You try keeping writing in squares, which is a right attitude. However, *fitting* the square doesn't mean *filling* the square; some kana have to be oblong relative to the square frame.
3. Some kana you see in textbook might have "hooks", but it's not what meant to be reproduced when you write yourself, especially with ball-point pen, as they are "trace" of pen that kept for stylistic reason. If you write at a fast pace, they do appear in your writing, though not needed to be awarely copied.
4. Finally, I have to say that your handwriting apparently seems non-native (besides well or badly shaped), but that may be because you haven't seen how they actually write. Googling "[手書き](https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbm=isch&q=%E6%89%8B%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D)" (handwriting) in Japanese will provide you tons of living examples.

[image: handwriting]

Comment: I appreciate all of the valuable feedback from everyone, and I assure you that I am taking everyone's feedback to heart. I will continue working on all of the points that were made. Hopefully my writing will soon be up to the standards of a native writer. Fingers crossed! Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your Hiragana is fine and legible. You write Japanese characters better than an expatriate I know who speaks Japanese pretty well. However your ね,れ,わ, all of which are combination of a straight line and a curved line, look somewhat awkward and constrained, because the head of vertical lines are all tilted to left. It should be drawn straight down as you see in the printed characters.

そ lacks the balance. It's top-heavy, and easily confused with a deformed た.

The ノ line of ゆ should be placed in the exact center of the character, keeping a good balance.

Answer (score 0):

Your hiragana is probably much more legible than when I was at third grade in Japan.

Your ね、れ、ゆ、わ、そ needs a bit of work on overall balance as the right side tend to be squished a bit. For your そ、the bottom curved stroke got squished because you made the top portion proportionately too large. Never the less, I could probably read a whole book in your writing with decent comfort.